# ¿Como mostrar o leer un dato guardado con el objeto Shared Preferences en encabezado navigation?

Tags: java, android-studio

en esta ocasión tengo un  `LoginActivity.java` el cual se inicia sesión correctamente, para guardar los datos he creado el objeto `Shared Preferences` solo para el correo electrónico, lo que quiero es que se muestre o lee en el encabezado del navigation drawer del Principalactivity ya que no he logrado llamar esa función.

**Login Metodo guardarPreferences**

```
public void guardarPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Datos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("email",texcorreo.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
}
```

**PrincipalActivity**

```
 public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
Toolbar toolbar;
NavigationView navigationView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);


    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Inicio");
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente obtén el objeto `SharedPreferences` y obtén el valor en base a la llave que previamente guardaste ("email") mediante el método `guardarPreferences()`:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Datos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//Lee valor guardado.
String valorEncabezado = sharedPreferences.getString("email", "");
```

Comment: Que tal amigo, le agregue el getHeaderView  y me funciono junto con la parte del código que me diste como respuesta.

Comment: Excelente amigo, saludos.